# Why is Leibniz notation more popular than Newton's notation?

Tags: calculus, notation, education, mathematicians

I need help ascertaining which calculus notation is more preferred amongst mathematicians according to their home countries, and why. I have tried looking for a census or survey of some sort that answers my question. Does anyone have access to this information?

Comment: If asking for educational purposes, you might want to try over at https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If interested more in the historical aspects, consider trying https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ on the history of science and mathematics

Comment: See the post [Why do we use Leibniz's “version” of calculus instead of Newton's?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11973/why-do-we-use-leibnizs-version-of-calculus-instead-of-newtons)

Comment: And see also [this post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/is-it-true-that-leibniz-introduced-constant-variable-and-function).

Answer (score 2):

It is often more useful in some contexts. I will give an example:

1. Given some function $f(x)$, we can either write $\dot{f}$ (Newton) or $\frac{df}{dx}$ (Leibniz). It just boils down to preference. However given some function $f(x, y)$ if we take the implicit derivative with respect to only one variable we typically don't write $\dot{f}(x, y)$ as that doesn't contain any additional information on which variable $f$ is being differentiated with respect to.
   $$\frac{d}{d x}f(x, y)$$
   Makes 'more sense' to use. An example is the use of Leibniz's notation in multivariable calculus

Another reason

1. Given some function $y$, we can use the chain rule:
   $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dz}\frac{dz}{dx}$$
   Which works and suggests that Leibniz's notation treats derivatives as fractions. This is due to the fact that Leibniz thought of derivatives as quotients, and while this is mathematically incorrect, it stuck around for reasons like the example above

---

Different countries and/or institutions will have different historical influences and curriculum choices that could determine whether one notation is preferred over the other. However, it is important to note that both notations are widely used and accepted. In modern day mathematical literature it seems preferrential to use Leibniz's notation for the reasons above

Comment: About 1. The modern notation for partial derivatives is due to [Adrien-Marie Legendre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative), not Leibniz.

Comment: @KurtG. I should have used regular $dx$ notation previously stating it is implicit differentiating- Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: If $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is a differentiable function, then I would interpret $f'(x,y)$ to mean the Fréchet derivative of $f$ at $(x,y)$. In this context, there is no such thing as "the derivative with respect to a variable". In order to make sense of the notation $\frac{d}{dx}f(x, y)$, you have to be thinking of $f(x,y)$ as a function of one variable $x$, so that $y$ is actually a notational shorthand for $g(x)$, where $g$ is some function of one real variable.

Comment: @Joe 'Implicit' derivative with respect to a variable

Comment: @Mako: I don't understand what you mean by that. What part of my comment are you addressing?

Comment: @Joe I agree that there is no such thing as "the derivative with respect to a variable" in the contect of $f(x, y)$. But it does make sense to conisder "the implicit derivative with respect to a variable"

Comment: Another remark: the notation $f'(x)$ is due to [Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Lagrange's_notation). Newton wrote $\dot f\,.$

Comment: @Mako: Indeed, it does make sense. But you are not taking the derivative of $f$ when you consider its "implicit derivative". You are taking the derivative of the composition of $f$ with the map $x\mapsto(x,g(x))$, and the Leibnizian notation obscures this.

Comment: @Joe Yes you are correct. My point still stands in regards to the use of notation, but I should be more specific- Please suggest how to improve the answer

Comment: @KurtG. I had no idea... I corrected it, and thankfully the reasoning of the post still stands as the ' is replaced with $\dot{ }$

Comment: @Mako: I don't have any concrete suggestions for how to improve the answer, unfortunately. My original point was just that I think Leibnizian notation is confusing in the multivariable context, and I tried to explain for why. I have definitely heard other mathematicians express a similar opinion on this matter. I think the reason that Leibnizian notation has stuck around is that it is very useful suggestive in the single-variable context. I think that there are better notations in the multivariable one.

Comment: Apparently Newton's notation was looked down upon by continental mathematicians of that time. They called it ["dot-age"](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/search?q=newton+dot-age). The English word "dotage" means senility. Rough times, even then.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite notation is Weierstraß's notation
$$
f(x_0+v)=f(x_0)+J_{x_0}\cdot v + r(v)
$$
where for the remainder function holds $\displaystyle{\lim_{v \to 0}\dfrac{r(v)}{\|v\|v}=0}.$ I like it since it clearly distinguishes the different parts of a derivative: function $f$, location $x_0$, direction $v$, linear approximation $\dfrac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$, linear functional $v\mapsto J_{x_0}\cdot v$ and higher order terms $r(v).$ This notation where $J$ is the Jacobi matrix and $v$ the direction of change becomes
$$
f(x_0+h)=f(x)+\underbrace{\left. \dfrac{d}{dx}\right|_{x_0}f(x)}_{=f'(x_0)} \cdot h + O(h^2)
$$
in the case of only one real dimension of $x$. All information is contained:

- a derivative is a local property (valid in a neighborhood of $x_0$)
- a derivative is a slope ($f'(x_0)$)
- the derivative as the result of differentiation is again a function ($x_0\mapsto f'(x_0)$)
- the derivative is a linear function with the direction as its variable ($h \mapsto f'(x_0)\cdot h$))
- differentiation is a linear operator ($D=\frac{d}{dx}:f\mapsto f'$)
- and a derivative is always directional ($h$)

We get very different perspectives depending on which of these quantities we consider a variable, and which we consider a parameter and misunderstandings are often based on confusion about which perspective is meant in a specific context. And in more than one dimension, even more perspectives are possible (linear functionals, sections of tangent bundles, etc.). Physicists use all of them.

So my answer to your question is: use the notation that fits best to your perspective. Leibniz's notation strengthens the perspective of a linear operator but only because people usually forget the locality of differentiation when they write
$$
\dfrac{df}{dx}\;\text{ and mean }\;\left. \dfrac{d}{dx}\right|_{x=x_0}f(x)
$$
whereas Newton's notation emphasizes on the resulting function
$$
x_0\longmapsto f'(x_0)
$$
as the result of differentiation which lacks the notation of a direction since there is only one direction in the one-dimensional case.

**Summary**: Newton's notation is harder to generalize than Leibniz's notation, and both are still less informative than Weierstraß's notation. To decide Leibniz or Newton means to decide what you want to neglect.